# Simple algebra Doubt while solving Question based on divisiblity

Tags: combinatorics

$4m(2m+1)(m+1)=4×3!$

How??
Please explain how $m(2m+1)(m+1)$ is 3!

Comment: At least one of $m, m+1, 2m+1$ will be a multiple of three, and at least one of $m, m+1$ will be a multiple of $2$.  It follows that $m\cdot (m+1)\cdot (2m+1)$ is a multiple of $3$ and a multiple of $2$ and is therefore a multiple of $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m(2m+1)(m+1)=\dfrac{2m(2m+1)(2m+2)}4$$

whose numerator is the product of three consecutive integers

As $(3,4)=1$

$3\mid2m(2m+1)(2m+2)\implies3\mid m(2m+1)(m+1)$

Alternatively, $$m(2m+1)(m+1)=m(2m^2+3m+1)\equiv-m(m-1)(m+1)\pmod3$$

But $m(m-1)(m+1)$ again is the product of three consecutive integers

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: How these are consecutive terms....confused

Comment: Guruji ...how these are consecurive terms

Comment: @Lucifer how are $2m, 2m+1$ and $2m+2$ consecutive integers?  Did you really just ask that?  A sequence of integers are called consecutive integers if each integer is equal to $1$ plus the previous integer.  Here the first integer is $2m$.  Then, adding $1$ to that we get $2m+1$.  Adding $1$ to that gives us $2m+2$.  Alternatively, if you are asking why $(m-1),m,(m+1)$ are consecutive integers, the same thing applies except here $m-1$ is the first term.  Adding one to that gives us $m$, and adding one to *that* gives $m+1$.

Comment: $m$ -> $(m+1)$ -> $(2m+1)$ how $(2m+1)$ is generated from $(m+1)$ by adding 1 ?

Comment: @Lucifer noone said that $m, m+1, 2m+1$ are consecutive.  We *are* saying however that $2m, 2m+1, 2m+2$ are consecutive, and we can see $2m, 2m+1, 2m+2$ in the numerator after a little bit of algebraic manipulation, the only really necessary steps in seeing this is in recognizing that $m = \frac{2m}{2}$ and that $m+1 = \frac{2m+2}{2}$